# ASP.NET Core Web API custom route not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API project, and the following controller:

```
[Route("/api/v0.1/controller")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet("/test")]
   public ActionResult Test() { return null; }
}
```

but when I run the project, at */api/v0.1/controller/test* I get "page not found" and I don't see where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method route template contains prefixed `/`, due to that, the app route couldn't find the appropriate path.

Modify test method route template as follows.

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public ActionResult Test() { return null; }
```

More at [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.0)