# ASP.NET Core custom route not working with web api 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to ASP.NET Core Web API and trying to implement a custom route.
Here is my controller:

```
using ...

namespace FoodDeliveryServer.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MenusController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly FoodDeliveryContext _context;

    public MenusController(FoodDeliveryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Menus
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenu_1()
    {
        return _context.Menu;
    }

    // rest of the methods

    // POST: api/Menus
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostMenu([FromBody] Menu menu)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Menu.Add(menu);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetMenu", new { id = menu.Id }, menu);
    }

    // POST: api/Menus/filter
    [HttpPost("filter", Name = "Filtermenu")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FilterMenu([FromBody] bool isActive)
    {
        return Ok(_context.Menu.Where(m => m.IsActive == isActive));
    }

    private bool MenuExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.Menu.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
}
```

Now, I'm trying to hit the **filter** route from POSTMAN and getting 404. Other standard routes are working fine.

```
POST
http://localhost:5000/api/Menus/filter

Body -> raw -> JSON

{
    "isActive": true
}

Headers -> Accept -> application/json
Headers -> Content-Type -> application/json
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I looked at this link also but still having problems:

[ASP.Net Core Web API custom route not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798420/asp-net-core-web-api-custom-route-not-working)

Comment: Have you done a full rebuild? Sometimes build doesn't seem to refresh everything.

Comment: Yes I did :(  still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[Route("")]` decorator on your actions too. Otherwise it will create routes upon what you defined in StartUp.Configure.

```
// POST: api/Menus/filter
[Route("filter")]
[HttpPost("filter", Name = "Filtermenu")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FilterMenu([FromBody] bool isActive)
{
    return Ok(_context.Menu.Where(m => m.IsActive == isActive));
}
```

Should work for you.
The '/api/Menus/' part will be inherited from your `[Route("api/[controller]")]` definition on controller level

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the help of @Marius. Here is what I did:

```
    // POST: api/Menus/filter
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("filter", Name = "Filtermenu")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FilterMenu([FromBody] Menu menu)
    {
        return Ok(_context.Menu.Where(m => m.IsActive == menu.IsActive));
    }
```

Looks like, we need to provide a class to read FromBody